# Query Votes table top items based on a percentage

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, count, postgresql-9.4

I have a table of Votes that looks like:

`id, type, scope, region, UserId, ItemId, updatedAt, createdAt`

I am trying to total the top items by percentage based on up votes / total votes.

Last piece is I want a `WHERE` clause for the votes for `createdAt` between two timestamps.

I feel like this is a very normal thing to query for getting statistics. But I am not sure how to go about this.

The closest I have gotten is:

```
SELECT "Votes"."ItemId", count("Votes"."ItemId") tots, count("Votes"."type" = 'up') AS yes, count("Votes"."type" = 'down') AS NO
FROM "Votes"
WHERE "Votes"."ItemId" IN (
    SELECT "Votes"."ItemId" FROM "Votes"
)
GROUP BY "Votes"."ItemId"
```

Which is a long ways from what is need. Hence why I would love some help here. Been having a really hard time finding good sql resources on this kind of stuff.

Comment: Are you using sql server or mysql or postgresql?

Comment: Why not store the up/down of vote using 1/-1 to make getting sum of votes easier? Just a side thought.

Comment: I am using postgresql for the query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CASE` statement to use 1 for each up vote and -1 for down vote and get sum of them

```
SELECT ItemId, SUM(CASE [type] WHEN 'up' THEN 1 WHEN 'down' THEN -1 END)
FROM Votes
WHERE createdAt >= 'startTime'
AND createdAt <= 'endTime'
GROUP BY ItemId
```

Comment: This is REALLY an interesting way to do the query. I guess one of the things I'd like to do is get back the items data really just enhanced by up, down, total and percent. I really like this way of selecting them for the sum though also so even adding this could be really great.

Comment: Giorgi Nakeuri's answer is complete version of mine with the all requirements you need. You just need to add the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select itemid, 
       sum(case when type = 'up' then 1 else 0 end) up,
       sum(case when type = 'down' then 1 else 0 end) down,
       sum(1) total,
       100.0*sum(case when type = 'up' then 1 else 0 end)/sum(1) upperc,
       100.0*sum(case when type = 'down' then 1 else 0 end)/sum(1) downperc
from votes
group by itemid
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1337d/6

Comment: This is GREAT. I am getting very close to the results I was hoping for now.

    SELECT "ItemId", 
       sum(CASE WHEN type = 'up' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) up,
       sum(CASE WHEN type = 'down' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) down,
       sum(1) total,
       round(100.0*sum(CASE WHEN type = 'up' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end)/sum(1), 2) percentage,
       sum(CASE WHEN type = 'up' THEN 1 ELSE -1 end)
FROM "Votes"
WHERE "Votes"."createdAt" BETWEEN '2015-05-19T20:00:00+00:00' AND '2015-05-20T00:00:00+00:00'
GROUP BY "ItemId" ORDER BY SUM DESC

Comment: Thanks @giorgi-nakeuri so many things to learn. Not even sure where to begin.

Comment: Is there a way to get the ranking appending to these based on the query? like 1-100?

Comment: Basically I need to do this.

1. Get all items at X createdAt date.
2. Count all votes for those items
3. Sort by the rank in which they have votes. 1-X
4. Have the total votes, total up votes, total down votes, percentage and sum.